# after installing image crop picker and debug problem

Tags: react-native-image-picker

my all project is working fine but when i install **image crop picker** dependency then it shows the error even there is no build.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Error given below

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> F:\bgbyteappfolder\newbgb\node_modules\react-native-image-crop-picker\android\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-14:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

BUILD FAILED in 31s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API..

i Am expecting rapid action on this failure stackoverflow family

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your gradle version by adding classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1' in your android/build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
     dependencies { 
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1' 
     } 
}
```

After this clean your build folder by:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

at that time when i posted this question I was almost a beginner for react native. now I understand why this problem occurred.

just add all android gradle settings and all. it will work fine.